# jMeter POST request viewing freezes - how to hide request data

Tags: user-interface, post, file-upload, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I am using the HTTP Request sampler in jMeter to send a large amount of data. I am reading in the data from a file using ${__FileToString(/Sample.pdf,,)}.

This works, but when I go to view the sampler in the results tree, jMeter freezes because there is too much data. I have tried resetting various parameters to no avail.

I noticed that when you use the "file upload" feature, jMeter embeds the data but does not show it. Instead you see: <actual file content, not shown here>.

Is there any way to hide data in the request in order to prevent freezing?

Answer (score 0):

First of all what is your JMeter version? It might be the case you're suffering from [JMeter bug 5128](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/issues/5128) and if you upgrade to [JMeter 5.5](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-5-5)

I can only think of the following workaround:

1. Disable [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener completely
2. Add [Simple Data Writer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer) listener configured like here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/carrk.jpg
3. Run your test
4. When your test finishes open the `debug.xml` file with View Results Tree listener - you will be able to see the response but your large request will not be there so JMeter GUI shouldn't "freeze". You won't be able to see the request data, it will be showing `null`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsnEa.jpg